# Forking issue in github

Tags: github

I have forked a git repo from another user's git repo(say Y), who in turn forked from an open source's main git repo(say X).Y has changes as compared to X.So I have a git repo,say Z, now containing same changes as Y.
Now I want to know what changes Z has compared to X.
So I try to fork from X to get original version of files so that I can compare those files with verions in Z.
But when I try to do so, git takes me to Z.I am not able to have a fork from X.

Am I doing it wrong way?

Comment: You already have an (indirect) fork of X. Just add another remote to the original X repo, fetch from that remote, and you can compare the files in your branches with the files in X's branches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.